# Invalid argument JavaScript exception in IE 8 issue with ExtJS in moveItem function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, exception, extjs4, invalid-argument

Below is a code snippet from the file ext-all-dev.js.  The JavaScript exception below only happens in Internet Explorer 8 (IE).  I have not tried any other versions of Internet Explorer.  When I place a break-point on this line of code when running my application, the browser freezes in IE.  So I don't have a way to troubleshoot this in IE.  Is there an easy way to tell what code might be calling this line?  I'm getting a sense that some drag and drop functionality may be causing this (because of the function comment), but that's a guess.  My only option right now is to start tracing backwards using Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox.  I'm just looking for advice on troubleshooting unless you know what might cause this.

```
/**
 * Moves Component to the provided target instead.
 * @private
 */
moveItem : function(item, target, position) {
        target = target.dom || target;
        if (typeof position == 'number') {
            position = target.childNodes[position];
        }
        target.insertBefore(item.el.dom, position || null);  // line 51942
        item.container = Ext.get(target);
        this.configureItem(item);
    },
```

**Exception:**

```
Invalid argument.
ext-all-dev.js line 51942 character 9
```

Comment: try to add console.log(item +'/'+target+'/'+position); into moveItem function and show the result here.

Comment: LOG: [object Object]/[object HTMLBodyElement]/[object HTMLDivElement]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placed the tree drag and drop plugin fully qualified class name into the requires config.